# Where to Get Software design feedback

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, architecture

I know this site is for very specific programming questions. Does anyone have any recommendations for sites that allow longer discussions on technology choices and perhaps even discussion of specific software designs for new projects?  Sometimes getting a few good people to look through a proposal can help you avoid major headaches by pointing out better design alternatives.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Based on that link/question, "Programmers" isn't for discussion.  Is there one where that would be for discussions and/or posting  architecture/software design document for review?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about modeling your future product, come here to SO with UML or modeling tags.

Technology choices are for [Programmers site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Questions on Software design are for SO if you have a question as:

> I have tried ... and don't like the results because of... What can I do?
>
> How to realize ... in ... technology? That ... and this ... won't help.
>
> How this operation ... can be done in ... technology.
>
> How this thought ... could be expressed in UML?
>
> Have I my UML diagram correct?
>
> I organized my classes/project so... and obviously, got lost. Is it workable? Can it be workable this way? What I have to change?

Questions of type:

> How to do ..., I don't know how to start?
>
> How such project ... can be organized?
>
> What technology to use for...

are rather for Programmers, too.

I.e., you are coming here to SO with a piece of done work. To Programmers it is allowed to come in search for the starting step or for the deeper philosophy of the problem.